# Android Clear Some Activity on Back Stack

Tags: android

Let Say I have 
A -> B -> C -> D
or
A -> C-> D

when D is finish I want to Back but skip C, it will back to A or B.

But When User use back button it will back normally
D -> C -> B -> A
or D -> C -> A

How we can do it in android?

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult` for starting new Activity and send a flag back to Previous `Activity` to finish or not .. If its case dependent only otherwise you can finish C before moving to D ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code in B Activity

```
public void gotoC()
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
}

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 10:


            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

ForwardActivityResult in C Class when you call Intent to go D Activity

```
 public void gotoD()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.C, D.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
}
```

In D Activity GO to B activity Call RESULT_OK

```
public void gotoB()
{
Intent intent = new Intent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

in manifest while declaring activity for activity B

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this code before open D `finish()`

Comment: I think i cant use it, because when user press back button I want it back normally