# How to maintain startActivityForResult for single activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one scenario to main with activities..

I have three activities A, B, C

Now I am calling C from A

A-->C

and in C I have onBackPress

Same way using startActivity for result

B-->C

So in my A and B I am using StartActitivity for result and maintaining in OnActivityForResult..

Activity A

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AddNewAddress.class);
i.putExtra("addresstype", addressType);
startActivityForResult(i, 10);
```

And in `OnActivityResult` of A

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2


        switch (requestCode) {

            case (10): {
                // do this if request code is 10.
                addressType=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
                getAddressList(userId,addressType);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                addrListModels.clear();
            }
            break;


        }

    }
```

Same thing I am doing in B as well....

Now in C

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",addresstype);
        setResult(10,intent);
        finish();
    }
```

And crash is happening

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Comment: add stack trace .

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841785/android-clear-some-activity-on-back-stack/55842069#55842069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `super.onBackPressed();` in C's `onBackPressed` method,please have a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AddNewAddress.class);

            i.putExtra("addresstype", addressType);
            startActivityForResult(i, 10);

    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",addresstype);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }

    onActivityResult use RESULT_OK

        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case 10:
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

@jiajiagu response is ok, don't call `super.onBackPressed` if you use `finish`.

However, as @mayur-panchalwhen try to say, if you use `startActivityForResult`, you don't need to return the `requestCode`. 
The system already knows which `Activity` is returning.

You need to return the `resultCode`.

ResultCode could be `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED`.

So, when finishing an Activity use

```
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

In `onActivityResult` test `requestCode` to identify which `Activity` is returning and `resultCode` to know if the result was successful.